# Determine how many capturing groups are in a javascript regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a utility to merge multiple regular expressions into one. I want to support replace with a function, but that means I need to have an offset for the capturing groups so I can pass the correct arguments to the replacer function. Here's the simplest solution I have found:

```
function countCapturingGroups(regexp) {
  var count = 0;
  regexp.source.replace(/(\\*)\((\?:)?/g,
      function(full, backslashes, nonCapturing) {
    if (backslashes.length % 2 === 0 && !nonCapturing) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  return count;
}
```

This supports:

1. Any number of backslashes (an even number means the backslash is itself escaped)
2. Non-capturing groups, e.g. `/(?:this)/`

Am I overlooking any other valid ways to use parentheses that won't capture content?

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/RHdPP/

Comment: what if the regex you're trying to parse is simply `/\(/`? it's an escaped paren, non-capturing, and the regex has an odd number of parens... parens won't ALWAYS be balanced...

Comment: I'm only counting opening parens.

Comment: `countCapturingGroups(/\(/) // returns 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
function countCapturingGroups(regex) {
    var count = 0;
    regex.source.replace(/\[(?:\\.|[^\\\]])*\]|\\.|(\()(?!\?)/g,
        function (full, capturing) {
            if (capturing) count++;
        });
    return count;
}
```

- `\[(?:\\.|[^\\\]])*\]` — Matches character classes, like `[abc]`.
- `\\.` — Matches escaped characters.
- `(\()(?!\?)` — Matches opening parenthesis, that are not non-capturing nor look-ahead.
- Any other regex construct can be safely skipped.

Comment: Nice! Somehow I'd never noticed the pattern that all non-capturing constructs start with `(?`. That's helpful. I'm working on some test cases to add to the question.

Comment: @theazureshadow Any progress?